# data being inserted into MySQL but not made permanent - Python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I'm using `MySQLdb` to manipulate a `MySQL` database, and I have this following routine, to inject some data in a table called `urls`:

```
def insert_urls(dbconn, filenames):
    root = "<path>/"
    link = "http://<url>/"
    for f in filenames:
        filename = root + f + ".html"
        local_url = link + f + ".html"
        print(filename, local_url)
        sql = """
        INSERT INTO urls(url, filename) VALUES('%s', '%s');
        """ % (local_url, filename)
        print(sql)
        dbconn.execute_query(sql)
```

the declaration of the `urls` table is found here:

```
def create_urls_table():

    sql = """
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS urls (
            id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            url BLOB NOT NULL,
            filename BLOB NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY(id)
        ) ENGINE=INNODB;
    """
    return sql
```

`dbconn` is an object of the class `Dbconn`, defined as:

```
class Dbconn:
    def __init__(self,
                 host="",
                 user="",
                 pwd="",
                 database=""):

        self.host = host
        self.user = user
        self.pwd = pwd
        self.db = database
        self.cursor = None
        self.conn = None

        try:
            self.conn = MySQLdb.connect(host=self.host,
                                        user=self.user,
                                        passwd =self.pwd,
                                        db=self.db)
            self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
            print "Connection established"
        except MySQLdb.Error, e:
            print "An error has occurred ", e

    def execute_query(self, sql=""):
        try:
            self.cursor.execute(sql)
        except MySQLdb.Error, e:
            print "An error has occurred ", e
```

After running the procedure `insert_urls` I get the following output:

```
  INSERT INTO urls(url, filename) VALUES ('http://<url>/amazon.html','<path>/amazon.html');
  INSERT INTO urls(url, filename) VALUES('http://<url>/linkedin.html', '<path>/linkedin.html');
  INSERT INTO urls(url, filename) VALUES('http://<url>/nytimes.html', '<path>/nytimes.html');
```

which I was able to inject manually into `MySQL` through the command line.
However doing a `SELECT * FROM urls` query I found nothing. After I inserted two lines manually I got:

```
mysql> select * from urls;
+----+------------------------------------------------+------------------------+
| id | url                                            | filename               |
+----+------------------------------------------------+------------------------+
| 19 | http://<url>/yelp.html                         | <path>/yelp.html       |       
| 29 | http://<url>/amazon.html                       | <path>/amazon.html     |
+----+------------------------------------------------+------------------------+
```

Please note that the `id` value is being incremented ... which it may means data is being inserted, but not made persistent? Could someone please help me with that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably using a transactional database, in which case you must call

```
self.conn.commit()
```

(Indeed, INNODB is a transactional database.)

---

You could incorporate `commit` into `execute_query`:

```
def execute_query(self, sql=""):
    try:
        self.cursor.execute(sql)
    except MySQLdb.Error as e:
        print "An error has occurred ", e
        self.conn.rollback()
    else:
        self.conn.commit()
```

However, there could be situations where you wish to execute a number of queries before you call `commit` or `rollback`. In that case you would want to remove `commit` from `execute_query` and either call `commit` explicitly when desired, or use a context manager to call `commit` when you exit the `with`-suite.

---

Note that `MySQLdb` connections are context managers. You can write

```
connection = MySQLdb.connect(
    host=config.HOST, user=config.USER,
    passwd=config.PASS, db=config.MYDB, )

with connection as cursor:
    cursor.execute(...)
```

and the connection will call `connection.commit()` upon exiting the `with-suite`, or `connection.rollback()` if there was an exception.
Here is the code that controls this in MySQLdb.connections.py:

```
def __enter__(self): return self.cursor()

def __exit__(self, exc, value, tb):
    if exc:
        self.rollback()
    else:
        self.commit()
```

Answer (score 2):

After your `execute()` statement, call `commit()`:

```
self.cursor.execute(sql)
self.conn.commit()
```

For more info, see: [python mysql insert data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5687718/584846)

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "download_page.py", line 122, in <module>
    main()
  File "download_page.py", line 118, in main
    insert_urls(dbconn, filenames)
  File "download_page.py", line 95, in insert_urls
    dbconn.execute_query(sql)
  File "C:\performance\Iperf\dbconn.py", line 127, in execute_query
    self.cursor.commit()
AttributeError: 'Cursor' object has no attribute 'commit'

Comment: Oops, that was supposed to be `self.conn.commit()`.  Fixed.