# Python insert data into MySQL

Tags: python, mysql

I've encounter a problem when i try to insert values into mysql using python connector.
The problem is that i'm trying to pass an input as a value in mysql, but the input is added as name of the table instead of value of field. Can anyone let me now what am i doing wrong?

My code is:

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode
def main():
    try:
        connection= mysql.connector.connect(user='root',passwd='',host='localhost',port='3306', database='game_01')
        print("Welcome")
        name_of_char = input("Your name?: ")
        con = connection.cursor()
        con.execute("INSERT into charachter (name,intel,strenght,agil) values(%s,0,0,0)" % str(name_of_char))
        con.execute("SELECT * FROM charachter")
        for items in con:
            print(items[1])
    except mysql.connector.Error as err: 
        print(err)
    else:
         connection.close()
main()
```

Thanks.

P.S 
The error is : 1054: Unknown column in 'field list'. I forgot to mention that in the post. It seems if i enter the tables attribute,it will work but won't add any value.

Comment: you can't save anything to table? what is the exception error ?

Comment: The error is : 1054: Unknown column in 'field list'. I forgot to mention that in the post. It seems if i enter the tables attribute,it will work but won't add any value.

Comment: make sure you have `name`,`intel`,`strenght`,`agil` in your table. The error occurs when you do not have a column in the table.

Answer (score 3):

if you using MySQLdb driver , after execute the query that insert into database or update , you should use connection.commit() to complete saving operation.

try this:

```
con = connection.cursor()
con.execute("INSERT into `charachter` (`name`,`intel,`strenght`,`agil`) values('%s',0,0,0)" % str(name_of_char))
connection.commit()
```

if you use any other driver , you should set the auto_commit option true.

see this:
[How can I insert data into a MySQL database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687718/python-mysql-insert-data?rq=1)

Comment: this answer is correct but i rather than use ORM such as peewee
http://peewee.readthedocs.org

Comment: ORMs are the best for most mvc frameworks db connection. But for tiny scripts maybe the raw query down the job quickly. But I prefer to use orms everywhere! and perhaps someone didn't like to use it.