# Blender Python MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, blender

can someone help me solve this problem?

I'm using Blender 2.74 and Python 3.4 with the correct connector to MySQL. By the way, I'm just a beginner in using Blender and Python. What I want is to make a login UI and save the inputted name into the database, but my code seems a bit off or totally wrong. When I run the code, it didn't save the value in the variable, but when i try to run it in python IDE it worked.

Here's the code:

```
import sys

sys.path.append('C:\Python34\Lib\sitepackages')
sys.path.append('C:\Python34\DLLs')

import mysql.connector

import bge
bge.render.showMouse(1) 

cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
own = cont.owner 

sensor = cont.sensors ["input"]

#this variable suppose to get the inputted name
pname = ""

db = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='', host='localhost',    database='database')

cursor = db.cursor()

add_player = ("INSERT INTO table " "(PlayerName) " "VALUES (%s)")
data_player = (pname)
cursor.execute(add_player, data_player)

#The 2nd one that i tried, and the same error
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO storymode" "(PlayerName)" "VALUES (%(pname)s)")

db.commit() 

db.close()
```

My questions are:
Why it always have an error saying syntax error near the %s;Am I missing something in the code or do i need an add-on/s to make it work properly?Thank you very much for reading my post and for the people who will give their opinions.

Comment: I know neither Python nor Blender's interface to it, but I'm surprised that 'pname' would work without inverted commas.

Comment: I'm sorry, im just a newbie in python programming. what do you mean by inverted commas? are you referring to the variable ?

Comment: This -> ' <- is an inverted comma.

Comment: So that's what you mean by inverted comma. But, my problem is the code for inserting data, it seems that i'm missing something near the %s. But i will try the inverted comma to see if it can change my current problem. Thank you for giving your thoughts about this.

Comment: I tried the inverted comma in variable 'pname' = "Name" with name as a set value but a new error pops up: "SyntaxError: can't assign to literal". What does this mean?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Blender database using Python (errors)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30687155/blender-database-using-python-errors)

Comment: pname = 'Name' or "Name". Consider going through tutorials on how to assign to variables. As you are learning. Get the basics strong. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_variable_types.htm.  http://www.learnpython.org/en/Variables_and_Types

Answer (score 0):

prime facie,

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO storymode" "(PlayerName)" "VALUES (%(pname)s)")

should look like

cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO anooog1 VALUES (%s,%s)""",(188,90))
(ref: [How can I insert data into a MySQL database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687718/how-can-i-insert-data-into-a-mysql-database))

cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO storymode VALUES (%s)""", (pname))

Answer (score 0):

It seems you didn't say what is the player name which needs to be substituted for %s or %(pname)s to be inserted to table.

```
add_player = ("INSERT INTO table " "(PlayerName) " "VALUES (%s)" % ('Nastu'))

or

add_player = ("""INSERT INTO table (PlayerName) VALUES (%s)""" % ('Nastu'))
```

Both the above mentioned is same one of them using quote thrice is multiline string in Python, otherwise what you have used is will concatenate the strings.

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO storymode" "(PlayerName)" "VALUES (%(pname)s)"  % {'pname' : 'nish'})
```

Please see through parameterized queries which is related to this

[Does Python support MySQL prepared statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947750/does-python-support-mysql-prepared-statements)

[Python MySQL Parameterized Queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775296/python-mysql-with-variables)