# insert mysql table from python function

Tags: python, mysql, loops, insert

I'm very newbie to python and how its mysql connector works in any web application. I want to try something easy actually but got no idea how to work it out. I have this simple python script to make random numbers and allocate it in a variable. (numbers.py)

```
import random
number = random.radint(1,1000)
print number
```

and this very simple python script to make a table in a mysql database (try.py)

```
import MySQLdb as mdb

con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'testuser', 'test623', 'testdb');

with con:
         cur = con.cursor()
         cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Table_Try")
         cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Table_Try(Value INT)")
```

My question is how do I insert the field "Value" with the value from variable "number" in number.py, since they are different scripts. When the value is inserted, how do I displayed in a php page so it can show random values repeatedly in a endless loop when opened? I have searched tutorial links about this in google but none could answer my problem here.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `PHP`

Comment: check this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687718/how-can-i-insert-data-into-a-mysql-database

Comment: maybe, but could it actually be done? I'm very curious here and since I used mysql why don't I use php as well?

Answer (score 0):

you can insert values into the database as follows:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO db_name.Table(value) VALUES(%s)",[5])
```

In the above code c is my cursor and Table is my table in that database.
If you want to insert many values you can use `executemany` instead of execue