# Writing a dataframe from Python to MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, dataframe

I have a script that downloads data from an API and turns all of this info into a CSV. I need this data to be into a table in MySQL (I already created it and established the connection with MySQL Connector). Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I insert data into a MySQL database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687718/how-can-i-insert-data-into-a-mysql-database)

Comment: Any error message? Please be more specific about your problem.

Comment: too wise, please be more precise. importing csv data into MySql is something very well documented

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Pandas.DataFrame` has a method [to_sql](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) which writes a dataframe into a sql table.

Simplest way to use the method is to create a connection with sqlalchemy.(You will need to install `mysql-python`) and use `.to_sql` to read the data into the table.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('mysql://username:password@host:port/database') #change to connect your mysql
#if you want to append the data to an existing table
df.to_sql(name='SQL Table name',con=engine,if_exists='append',index=False) 

#if you want to create a new table 
df.to_sql(name='New SQL Table name',con=engine,if_exists='fail',index=False)
```

Please note that you will need to use param `dtype` to define the dtype of the table columns if you have created the table before hand.

Comment: @PaulaC, Glad I can help. Be sure to accept my answer.