# Not able to Commit data to database (using Python flask MySQL) even after using connection.commit()

Tags: python, mysql

My data is not being stored in db inspite of using connection.commit() in Python flask. Here is my code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
app = Flask(__name__)

def getMysqlConnection():

    mysql = MySQL()
    app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = "user_name"
    app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = "pass_string"
    app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = "db_name"
    app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = "hostname"

    mysql.init_app(app)

    connection = mysql.connect()
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    return {"cursor":cursor,"connection":connection}

cursor = getMysqlConnection()['cursor']   #####global variables####
connection = getMysqlConnection()['connection']

def main_function():
    cursor.execute("Insert into table_name "
                       "(col1,col2,col3,col4) "
                       "Values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",
                       (val1,vla2,val3,val4)
                       )
    connection.commit()
```

This is not saving code in the database and I don't know why.

Comment: i hope you are calling your main function

Comment: yeah @PaulNicolashunter. I m doing that. Any idea why problem is there?

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687718/how-can-i-insert-data-into-a-mysql-database) check this out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that the following code initializes the database connection two times?

```
cursor = getMysqlConnection()['cursor']   #####global variables####
connection = getMysqlConnection()['connection']
```

Try

```
db =  getMysqlConnection()
cursor = db['cursor']
connection = db['connection']
```

Comment: Thanks!!!!! @Isma. You are Awesome Buddy. How on earth I could miss that.... Took my 3 hours....